# SharpSVN wrong assembly

Tags: c#, svn, .net-assembly, sharpsvn

"Unable to find assembly 'SharpSvn, Version=1.7002.1998.12257, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d729672594885a28'."
http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/docs/walkthrough.htm#svn_checkout

doing everything just like in tutorial but have that problem

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to specify platform assembly to x64.